# How to apply or change a dropdown choice on multiple cells in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Here I am trying to apply the "Replied" choice for the selected range of cells instead of choosing one by one for each cell:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose "Replied" in one of those dropdowns, then copy the dropdown cell, select the other dropdown cells, and paste.